# Boutique Library: International Airports?

Tags: boutique, library-sound-effects

Would this SFX collection be valuable to you?:

International Airports ambience with walla and intercom announcements where possible.

China,
India,
Europe,
UK,
US,
Australia,
Russia,
Japan,
South America,
Central America,
the list goes on...

Answer (score 4):

Also, keep in mind that at least in the US, music is everywhere.  I've never been able to record in a US airport due to music and or TV playing in the background.  I still can't understand why we can't have spaces in this country that don't have music.

Comment: That is a good point! Although it doesn't happen much in Europe, at least in the airports i've been to. In restaurants to, it's rare having music playing.

Comment: Dunno, departure lounge back to London at JFK was pretty dull and boring to me compared to the great recording I got at Heathrow airport.

Comment: "I still can't understand why we can't have spaces in this country that don't have music."

+1

I was hunting for some homegrown restaurant ambiences/walla for a project recently and came up empty-handed because there's just Music. Everywhere. Franchises, mom and pop places, everywhere.

It got to the point where I was "auditioning" every spot on the strip by cracking the door, tilting the zeppelin/dead cat in while monitoring, and shutting it within two seconds when I heard the music playing.

Comment: I was pretty stunned a few years back to go into a K-Mart and hear absolutely no music playing. Really wished I had my recorder on me...

Comment: @Luca did you ask the establishment to shut it off for 5 minutes while you recorded a track?

Answer (score 2):

The elements would need to have a good amount of separation, ie. wallas not tied to p.a. announcements, since those often need to be kept on their own pre dubs and split out for foreign versions (M&E).  But yes, if properly mastered it would be a very handy collection of sounds.

Comment: Thanks, Jay. I asked because I'm going to be traveling the world, soon. I have also considered bringing at least a zoom with me to each restaurant I go to, so maybe I can make a foreign-language walla library as well. Would that be valuable, too?

Answer (score 1):

I personally have not come across the need for these sounds in my projects so far, but it is certainly the type of thing that when you need it quickly it would be a big pain to get, so I bet it could be useful too many people.

This library is already out there   http://www.soundscalpel.com/soundeffects/pack/airport-internal-ambiences/
Again I don't have it so I have no review as to its quality, but there is lots of room to cover more and varied airports worldwide.

I would say go for it.

Comment: Thanks! I just listened to a few of those sounds and they sound pretty good. But, I am sure I can find some more angles and ways to capture the airport. I'm going to be traveling quite a bit pretty soon and this idea crossed my mind. Thanks for the answer!